# cannot concatenate 'str' and 'float' objects

Tags: python, web2py

I am trying to concatenate a string from some list values in order to add some html attributes, however I get the error:

> cannot concatenate 'str' and 'float' objects

```
productlist = ["pedegree","chum", "ColesBrand"]

priceList = [6,5,3]

priceandproduct = []

for x,val in enumerate(productlist):
    priceandproduct.extend([productlist[x],priceList[x]])

myhtml = ""

for x in priceandproduct:
    myhtml = myhtml + x + "<br/>"

print priceandproduct
```

I presume this is because some of the elements are of type float and some are string. So I tried converting each element to string and then attempt concatenation.

```
  for x in priceandproduct:
        x = str(x)
```

This was to no avail.

Comment: `for x in priceandproduct: x = str(x)` doesn't put the new string version back into `priceandproduct`; it just calculates it and throws it away.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to actually modify the list, that would look like the following:

```
priceandproduct = [ str(x) for x in priceandproduct ]
```

Comment: If the answer worked, please mark it as the solution instead of commenting. It will help other in the future who may have the same issue, and it helps the responder, who put time in to help :)

Answer (score 0):

What if you changed this line:

```
priceandproduct.extend([productlist[x], str(priceList[x]]))
```

then your loop could be really simple:

```
myhtml = "<br />".join(priceandproduct)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
productlist = ["pedegree","chum", "ColesBrand"]
priceList = [6,5,3]

priceList = [str(x) for x in priceList]
priceandproduct = list(zip(productlist, priceList))

myhtml = ""

for x in priceandproduct:
    myhtml += ' '.join(x) + "<br/>"

print(priceandproduct)
print(myhtml)
```

Output:

```
[('pedegree', '6'), ('chum', '5'), ('ColesBrand', '3')]
pedegree 6<br/>chum 5<br/>ColesBrand 3<br/>
```