# Iterating through Geocoding API response in python

Tags: python, google-maps

I'm trying to find the `['locality', 'political']` value in the reverse geocoding Google Maps API.

I could achieve the same in Javascript as follows:

```
var formatted = data.results;
$.each(formatted, function(){
     if(this.types.length!=0){
          if(this.types[0]=='locality' && this.types[1]=='political'){
               address_array = this.formatted_address.split(',');
          }else{
               //somefunction
          }
     }else{
         //somefunction
     }
});
```

Using Python, I tried the following:

```
url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng='+lat+','+long+'&result_type=locality&key='+MAPS_API_KEY
results = json.loads(urllib.request.urlopen(url).read().decode('utf-8'))
city_components = results['results'][0]
for c in results:
    if c['types']:
        if c['types'][0] == 'locality':
            print(c['types'])
```

This gives me a bunch of errors. I'm not able to get my head around iterating through the response object to find the `['locality', 'political']` value to find the related City `short_name`. How do I go about solving this?

Comment: What are those errors? Are you by any chance [concatenating floats and strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26540270/cannot-concatenate-str-and-float-objects)?

Comment: @OliverW. I get a `Str indices must be integer` error.

Comment: please add the full traceback, so that we may see *where* that error pops up, rather than having to track your code.

Comment: @OliverW. Here you go: http://dpaste.com/1Y02ZQ2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to access the keys of a dictionary, but instead you are iterating over the characters of that key:

```
for c in results:
    if c['types']:
```

`results` is a dictionary (obvious from your `city_components=` line). When you type `for c in results`, you are binding `c` to the keys of that dictionary (in turn). That means `c` is a string (in your scenario, most likely all the keys are strings). So then typing `c['types']` does not make sense: you are trying to access the value/attribute `'types'` of a string...

Most likely you wanted:

```
for option in results['results']:
    addr_comp = option.get('address_components', [])
    for address_type in addr_comp:
        flags = address_type.get('types', [])
        if 'locality' in flags and 'political' in flags:
            print(address_type['short_name'])
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks for the explanation and correction! :)