# Python: how to parse Google API 'address_components' with elegance

Tags: python, json, google-maps

What's wrong with my code?

I'm retrieving JSON from Google API

I know I can do it [this way](https://gist.github.com/narnikgamarnikus/ca806ec61cd8c30669fc30b482f89a17) but I would rather check the JSON and retrieve the street `if i['types'] == 'street_number'`

```
if response_data2['status'] == 'OK':
    Googleplace_id = response_data2['result']['place_id'] 
    Googleid = response_data2['result']['id'] 
    GoogleName = response_data2['result']['name']
    for i in response_data2['result']['address_components']:
        if i['types'] == 'street_number':
        street = i['long_name']     
    GoogleLatitude = response_data2['result']['geometry']['location']['lat']
    GoogleLongitude = response_data2['result']['geometry']['location']['lng']
```

Python says: `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'street' referenced before assignment`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28350605/iterating-through-geocoding-api-response-in-python):

```
if response_data2['status'] == 'OK':
    Googleplace_id = response_data2['result']['place_id']
    Googleid = response_data2['result']['id']
    GoogleName = response_data2['result']['name']
    for types in response_data2['result']['address_components']:
        field = types.get('types', [])
        if 'street_number' in field:
            GoogleStreet_Number = types['long_name']
    GoogleLatitude = response_data2['result']['geometry']['location']['lat']
    GoogleLongitude = response_data2['result']['geometry']['location']['lng']
```

But this is not elegant at all :(

There must be a way to have something like

```
GoogleStreet_Number = response_data2['result']['address_components']['types' == 'street_number']['long_name']
```